# How to plot different groups with different colors using plot function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

Hi I have used following code to generate a plot a data in a matrix

```
#load the data
data <- read.table("hedge.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
data_matrix <- data.matrix(data)

#plot bcl2
plot(data_matrix["BCL2",],col="blue")
```

and I got following as the plot. But I need to plot 1:6, 7:49, 50:76 as three different colors?

Comment: What is `hedge.txt`? better provide code for a reproducible data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Answer without know what data and columns are inside your dataset is complicated.
You asked how to plot different groups with different colors, does your dataset have a column "group"? If yes you can use unclass instead of select the rows of each groups.
Please see a minimal reproducible dataset

```
df1=data.frame(val_x=runif(100,0,1),
               val_y=runif(100,0,1),
               group=c(rep("group1",33),
                       rep("group2",33),
                       rep("group3",34)))
```

and my suggestion for the plot

```
plot(df1[,"val_x"],col=c("red","green","blue")[unclass(df1$group)])
```

Comment: You should try: ```plot(df1[,"val_x"],df1[,"val_y"], col=c("red","green","blue")[as.factor(df1$group)])``` instead, as this actually produces a plot from your example.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610):

```
m <- matrix(runif(76*2), ncol=2)
```

2.Solution using base `R`:

This first call to `plot` serves just as a quick 'hack' to get the right sized axis

```
plot(m, color="white")
```

Now we plot the actual points with their colors:

```
points(m[1:6, ],col="red")
points(m[7:49, ],col="blue")
points(m[50:76, ],col="green")
```

This generates the following plot:

[image]